# What can I do to prevent my ball from scaling when I rotate the main controller (bone)

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I have set up 3 bones. Master (blue), main(green) and assistant bone (red). My intention was that, I want to be able to rotate my ball with the main bone, move and scale with the assistant bone.

The assistant bone works correctly when I move or scale it, but when I try to rotate the main bone I got this scaling effect. Please help me!

The ball to the left is the actual ball. The one to the right is a duplicate of the one to the left but this time I have rotated the main bone, thus, given me this effect.[image]

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve, but is sounds like looking into bone properties "Relations" group might help? Especially "Inherit Rotation" and "Inherit Scale" combo box?

Comment: Rafal, thanks for the tips. It gave me a new way to think about how to solve my problem. The reason why the ball scales whenever I rotate the main controller was because I assigned 100% weight to both the main bone and the assistant. To solve the problem I simply remove the entire weight from the assistant bone, and make it the child of the main bone, while master bone is the parent of the assistant bone. This gave me the effect I wanted. Thanks again 

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to help you to look at it in a "fresh" way! Probably even better than giving you an answer, as now, as you discovered it by yourself you will remember it for life :D And I can say, the way it clicks in your head, you might have quite a lot of fun with blender! ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely I will. Thanks again 